# Адаптивный веб-дизайн (Responsive Web Design): будущее

Tags: веб-дизайн, дизайн

Много читал на тему "отзывчевого" веб дизайна, кто не знает "это дизайн, который подстраивается под все экраны мобильных устройств" и не где не нашел, чтобы кто-то сказал что это в будущем будет использоваться везде. Как Вы считаете будет ли `responsive` дизайн везде, на всех сайтах в ближайшие лет 5-10? И как Вы думаете стоит ли создавать сайт с "отзывчивым" дизайном?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да. Очевидно, что интернет скоро станет полностью мобильным. Стационарами будут пользоваться только разработчики. Обычные же потребители контента будут пользоваться смартфонами / планшетами / etc.
Интернет, в перспективе, может появиться даже на экранах холодильников, часов и т.д.
Или вы думаете что кто-то сделает одно устройство с одним разрешением экрана и им будут пользоваться абсолютно все?

Comment: > интернет скоро станет полностью мобильным

Ну, что за чушь?

Answer (score 1):

Да, будет. Да, стоит.

Мне интересно, когда вы читаете книгу про HTML5, C++, Ruby или что-то иное, вам там пишут „эта технология будет супер-пупер и ее будут все использовать“? Сколько книг перечитал — ни разу не встречал.

Да и что уж Вы. На русском есть название для этого термина — „адаптивный веб-дизайн“.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте twitter bootstrap - он достаточно простой для начала использования